# Why is the BookmarkablePageLink class generic in Wicket?

Tags: java, generics, wicket

Does anyone know why the `BookmarkablePageLink` class is generic in wicket?  I have been creating new `BookmarkablePageLink<Object>(...)` just to avoid the compiler warnings.

Should I be choosing a different generic type?  A brief view of the code just confused me further about why it was generic.

Comment: I use `<Void>`, just to avoid the warnings.

Comment: Very cool, I will switch to Void.  I didn't realize Java had such an object.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a brief overview of the [javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html) it looks like the reason for generics can be seen in the abstract superclass [Link](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html). Specifically, a Link lets you associate with it a model object of a generic type via [setModelObject](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html#setModelObject%28T%29). So from their example, when you override [onClick](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html#onClick%28%29):

```
new Link<MyObject>("myLink") {
     public void onClick()
     {
         MyObject obj = getModelObject();
         setResponsePage(new MyPage(obj));
     }
}
```

You can access a relevant model object.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand why you would want to associate a model object with a link.  It's still not very clear.  In your example you don't set the link's model.  And if you did, you could just use that object directly in onClick (if it were final).

Comment: @schmmd in an anonymous class, yes. But if you write a custom Link class, the model is in the constructor and can't be referenced by methods.

Answer (score 5):

When Wicket 1.4 was introduced, the developers decided to generify the `Component` class. Since `BookmarkablePageLink` is a descendent of `Component` (like pretty much everything in Wicket), it became generic as well.

The [Wicket 1.4 migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migrating-to-wicket-14.html#MigratingtoWicket1.4-GenericsformostObjects) recommends using `Void` as the generic type for `BookmarkablePageLink`s, as well as other Wicket components that generic types don't really make sense for.